# App crashes after loading soundPool file 482 times

Tags: android, soundpool

I wonder why my app crashes after loading and playing a soundfile exactly 482 times?
On the 482:e click (listview) that loads and play a mp3 soundfile the following happends:

```
 10-20 01:28:38.454: V/MediaPlayer(14307): decode(1018, 58494525, 47481)
 10-20 01:28:40.424: I/System.out(14307): groupos i metoden getGroupId: 71
 10-20 01:28:40.489: I/System.out(14307): groupos i metoden getGroupId: 71
 10-20 01:28:40.489: V/SoundPoolThread(14307): Got message m=2, mData=480
 10-20 01:28:40.489: V/MediaPlayer(14307): decode(1020, 58494525, 47481)
 10-20 01:28:42.359: I/System.out(14307): groupos i metoden getGroupId: 71
 10-20 01:28:42.424: I/System.out(14307): groupos i metoden getGroupId: 71
 10-20 01:28:42.424: V/SoundPoolThread(14307): Got message m=2, mData=481
 10-20 01:28:42.424: V/MediaPlayer(14307): decode(1022, 58494525, 47481)
 10-20 01:28:44.244: I/System.out(14307): groupos i metoden getGroupId: 71
 10-20 01:28:44.314: I/System.out(14307): groupos i metoden getGroupId: 71
 10-20 01:28:44.314: V/SoundPoolThread(14307): Got message m=2, mData=482
 10-20 01:28:44.314: V/MediaPlayer(14307): decode(-1, 58494525, 47481)
 10-20 01:28:44.314: E/SoundPool(14307): Unable to load sample: (null)
 10-20 01:28:44.324: W/SoundPool(14307): Sample was not loaded. Waiting for 30ms.
 10-20 01:28:44.354: W/SoundPool(14307): Sample was not loaded. Waiting for 30ms.
 10-20 01:28:44.384: W/SoundPool(14307): Sample was not loaded. Waiting for 30ms.
 10-20 01:28:44.414: W/SoundPool(14307): Sample was not loaded. Waiting for 30ms.
 10-20 01:28:44.444: W/SoundPool(14307): Sample was not loaded. Waiting for 30ms.
 10-20 01:28:44.474: E/SoundPool(14307):   sample 482 not READY
```

And the stacktrace

```
  10-20 01:40:03.639: D/AndroidRuntime(22802): Shutting down VM
  10-20 01:40:03.639: W/dalvikvm(22802): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught      exception (group=0x40eb22a0)
  10-20 01:40:03.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22802): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  10-20 01:40:03.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):       android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-ldpi/sam.mp3 from  drawable resource ID #0x7f0203af
  10-20 01:40:03.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):  at       android.content.res.Resources.openRawResourceFd(Resources.java:994)
  10-20 01:40:03.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):  at android.media.SoundPool.load(SoundPool.java:191)
  10-20 01:40:03.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):  at  com.example.thai.PhraseActivity.loadSound(PhraseActivity.java:255)
  10-20 01:40:03.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):  at  com.example.thai.PhraseActivity.access$3(PhraseActivity.java:252)
  10-20 01:40:03.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):  at com.example.thai.PhraseActivity$2.onChildClick(PhraseActivity.java:130)
  10-20 01:40:03.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):  at android.widget.ExpandableListView.handleItemClick(ExpandableListView.java:590)
  10-20 01:40:03.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):  at android.widget.ExpandableListView.performItemClick(ExpandableListView.java:522)
  10-20 01:40:03.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3063)
  10-20 01:40:03.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):  at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3949)
  10-20 01:40:03.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
  10-20 01:40:03.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  10-20 01:40:03.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  10-20 01:40:03.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
  10-20 01:40:03.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  10-20 01:40:03.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  10-20 01:40:03.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
  10-20 01:40:03.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
  10-20 01:40:03.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  10-20 01:40:03.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22802): Caused by:   java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is  probably compressed
  10-20 01:40:03.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetFdNative(Native Method)
  10-20 01:40:03.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetFd(AssetManager.java:428)
  10-20 01:40:03.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):  at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResourceFd(Resources.java:991)
  10-20 01:40:03.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):  ... 17 more
```

And the source code:

```
  weakExpandableList.get().setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            Object e = (Object)adapter.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
            int nmbr_childs = adapter.getChildrenCount(groupPosition);
            final int group_position = groupPosition;

            // villkor för childitem. 
            switch (childPosition) {
                case 0:
                    // tester huruvida ett eller två childitems. returvärdet fyller ingen funktion.
                    int x = (nmbr_childs > 1) ? loadAnimation_singleView(v, childPosition) 
                        : loadAnimation_coupleView(v);

                    loadSound(0, group_position);  // Här uppstår krasch ibland!
                break;
                case 1:
                    loadSound(1, group_position);
                    loadAnimation_singleView(v, childPosition); 
                break;              
        }

        return true;
    }
    });  




    private void loadSound(int position, int group_position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            myVoice = soundPool.load(PhraseActivity.wr.get(), sound[group_position][0], 2);  // Här uppstår en crash ibland - resource not found exeption
            soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                    int status) {
                    soundPool.play(myVoice, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1.0f);
                } 
            });
        break;
        case 1:
            myVoice = soundPool.load(PhraseActivity.wr.get(), sound[group_position][1], 2);
            soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                    int status) {
                    soundPool.play(myVoice, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1.0f);
                } 
            });
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that you are not using SoundPool properly. Is this the same MP3 you are loading every time? It appears from the [Soundpool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) javadoc, that SoundPool allows you to load audio resources from disk, and then play them as many times as you wish. If you are loading and playing the same clip, or several clips each time, then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: ok, you mean I should only load a certain mp3-file one time. When its loaded I can play it as much as I want. hmmm ... I have about 1000 mp3-files in this app. Could I do it in another way - unload the sound after its played?

Comment: Yes. Keep the int returned from the `int load()` method. This is the soundId of the sound file. When you are done with it, call `unload(int soundId)`.